# Suggest a domain name for this site

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Last Chance — Top domain name: pauseforhelp.com. Speak now or forever hold your peace.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance-top-domain-name-pauseforhelp-com-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name gaming.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Post your ideas for a **dot-com domain name** for this website, which captures the spirit and intent of the site, namely:

> {name} is intended for expert and advanced gamers on all consoles and computers, including, but not limited to...
>
> - Windows PC
> - XBox and XBox 360
> - Playstation
> - Playstation Portable
> - Nintendo Wii
> - Nintendo DS
>
> …

Please follow these guidelines:

- **Check to see if the domain is taken <s>or squatted</s> *before* making the name suggestion.** <s>Squatted and</s> taken names, however clever, are not helpful. You can use [whois.net](http://www.whois.net) to check availability.
- **Post one domain per answer.** This makes the voting process much easier. If domains are very similar (e.g. "game" and "games"), they can be in the same answer.
- **Make sure the domain wasn't already suggested.** To search within this question, use a search query such as: `inquestion:1 "example.com"` replacing `example.com` with the domain to search for.
- **When coming back to this question, make sure to sort the answers "newest first"**, as to not miss new proposals.

Comment: @Robert - I posted the information as an answer because I couldn't edit the question - it's not Community Wiki

Comment: @ChrisF: Okay, thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: I miss my moderator capabilities on StackExchange...

Comment: What happens when someone comes along and squats the best answers to this question? I don't think this is a good idea...

Comment: @Ricket: I'm open to suggestion for a better procedure. Post your ideas and make it a feature-request. The same issue came up here (http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be) and it didn't happen. We're not paying ransom fees for a domain name so all the squatter is  doing is being spiteful. But, until it happens, it's not worth anticipating it as a major problem.

Comment: Also, we are still in private beta. One would hope that we'll have decided on an answer before open.

Comment: Could someone edit the obvious copy paste from the web apps site? /cc @rob @jeff

Comment: Aw, all the ones I wanted to suggest are registered. Does it have to be .com and not .net? Anyway, since they're taken but to get them off my chest anyway: killscreen.com, pausescreen.com, heylisten.com

Comment: @Alastar: this question is visible through the public API.

Comment: @Matt: I had thought of killscreen.com as well, and was very bummed to see it unavailable. It would certainly fit with the "failure" theme started by Stack Overflow and Server Fault.

Comment: HeyListen would have been awesome. I just raided TVtropes for a few gaming trope suggestions, for a moment it was looking like all of them had been squatted though.

Comment: anyone else a little nervous about how this is going?

Comment: What point is there in downvoting suggestions you don't like? Just upvote the ones you do like... yikes!

Comment: @Jon not saying I agree with the strategy, but down-voting as well as up-voting sort of gives your up-vote double the weight.

Comment: @antony - that's a problem. I started a meta suggestion on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56904/allow-diamond-mods-to-lock-out-downvoting-to-support-poll-election-type-questio

Comment: Someone seems to downvoted all new suggestions. Few at 0, few at -2, loads at -1

Comment: I'll be amazed if anything makes it over 10. I wish I had the rep necessary to view the actual upvotes.

Comment: @Noctrine there's a huge difference there. For example, at time of writing, the top one (pauseforhelp.com) has 17 upvotes and 11 downvotes.

Comment: Since the site went public, upvotes started really flowing in.

Comment: I splitted up [quicksave.com](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/407#407) and [quickload.com](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/515#515), so please feel free to redistribute your votes if you prefer quickload.com

Comment: Shameless plug for a less advert ridden whois: http://www.shrinkrays.net/tools/network-tools.aspx

Answer (score 43):

## quicksave.com

(Taken, but maybe...)

as opposed to [quickload.com](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/515#515)

Joel says [taken does not necessarily mean impossible](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

Since console games don't offer quicksave, you may consider this as a:

> "quick - save my char from dying in this unpauseable game"

Comment: These are two of the best names possible, and based on Joel's post in the SO blog they should be okay (they are squatted on, not actually used).

Comment: @Oak 2xthanks, I edited that info in

Comment: Far, far better than pauseforhelp IMO.

Comment: +1000 for quicksave.com, very memorable, I approve

Comment: Would it be one or the other or both, though?

Comment: @Ravn: From chat, it seems quicksave is preferable.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Ideally both just to make sure *we* are found. But the site can obviously have only one name...

Comment: Nice name but the reference might be lost for the console generation, and think of save as having other connotations

Comment: @Chris S: quicksave as in "quick - save my char from dying in this unpauseable game"?

Comment: these should be split up so they can be voted on separately. both could still be used, but a winner could be picked if only one was desired.

Comment: +1 for quicksave.com. I like the save/help synonym :)

Comment: @anthony.trupe you're right. Following the comments I assume the upvotes count for quicksave.com and I separated of quickload.com. @Everybody-who-disagrees is asked to swap his votes

Comment: @Tobias I haven't played a console game with quicksave, they've all been checkpoint based. Maybe I've been missing out

Comment: @Chris S: Unfortunately you're right, which is something I miss on consoles... That's why I suggested the alternative interpretation

Comment: I just liked the idea of the site being a quicksave for any gaming problem you may have.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is the best we can come up with

Comment: This just reminds me of Kwik Save, the supermarket chain in the UK (it may have closed down now).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Me too. It's still a great suggestion though.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but MMOs don't offer a save function _at all_....

Comment: @Bill Foecke: but one certainly would like to have one sometimes...

Comment: @Bill Foecke: Quick, Save my character from this instance ;)

Answer (score 23):

### [infinitelives.com](http://www.whois.net/whois/infinitelives.com)

Taken, but not used; perhaps for sale.

Comment: good, +1, though I sill prefer quicksave.

Answer (score 16):

## pauseforhelp.com

Comment: It doesn't flow well, imho; no ring to it. "Hey man, where did you find that out?" "Oh, I asked it on PauseForHelp."

Comment: @Corey: it could be that it's 3 words... where as the trilogy has kept to a 2 word domain name.

Comment: It's not just the three word thing. IMO thatonelevel flows much better.

Comment: I think pauseforhelp flows nicely. "that one level" doesnt IMO

Comment: Just curious: Is this a meme to gaming enthusiasts? Or is it just exactly what it sounds like?

Comment: @Robert I think it's exactly what it sounds like.

Comment: @Robert: It was just me brainstorming (hence the other tens of suggestions). It's something I do often in games: pause to look up help or walkthroughs or some other assistance.

Comment: @Robert There's 2 interpretations - either you pause and access the in-game help menu, or you pause the game so you can run to the instruction manual / online to look up how to get yourself out of a jam.

Answer (score 15):

## protip.com

Taken.

> A *protip* is a tip intended to convert you from a novice to an expert in one easy step.

Gaming + Experts = Protips.

Comment: Shoot at the boss until he dies.

Comment: I like this, but it's awfully generic. The name could apply perfectly well to any of the other SE sites.

Comment: @badp remember, at the Giant Enemy Crab, you attack its weak point for massive damage.

Answer (score 13):

## thatonelevel.com

[Gaming Trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThatOneLevel),  and what will probably bring many users here.

*Registered by Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. 2010-07-13.*

Comment: I like it - "where did you find that info?" "oh, I went to that one level dot com" :)

Comment: can't believe it's not squatted - but really it is not!

Comment: Really, I should [stop following links](http://xkcd.com/609/) to tvtropes

Comment: @Tobias I couldn't either.
@alexanderpas It was hard to find it without getting sucked in lol.

Comment: Has a great ring :)

Comment: I don't like it. My eye wants to parse it as "tha tone level" for some reason.. and I don't think it flows very well.

Comment: @Ziggamorph: do you know something we don't? whois information says GoDaddy has the address and indeed thatonelevel.com is currently parked.

Comment: It's registered by SO: http://who.godaddy.com/WhoIs.aspx?domain=thatonelevel.com&prog_id=godaddy

Comment: It's the height of the 't' that makes it read "tha tone level" at first, particularly to those accustomed to CamelCase.

Answer (score 10):

## respawnhere.com

Comment: I like it, available too: http://www.whois.net/whois/respawnhere.com

Comment: The problem I see with these "respawn" names is that many, if not most games do not have respawning and as such the term may not be known to everyone.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I agree, and also. Wow, this made it back up from the pit.

Comment: Punting it back down the pit.

Answer (score 8):

## throwingcontrollers.com

Comment: Funny because it's true.

Comment: I like throwncontrollers.com a little better than throwing.

Comment: @tzenes: maybe the gerund form sounds ok to me because i am a long-time Smashing Pumpkins fan...

Answer (score 8):

## extralife.com

parked domain

http://www.whois.net/whois/extralife.com

Answer (score 7):

Grr, all the good domains are being squatted on. How about:

### AlmostLoaded.com

Similar to 99percentcomplete.com, but less "spammy" looking and 2 words.

Comment: could also mean that your gun is almost reloaded

Answer (score 7):

## <del>**gameover.com**</del>

<del>displays a maintaince page for over 2 years according to the [Internet Archive](http://bit.ly/bGz3aw), so it might be buyable
(creds to [Ivo Flipse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/10/ivo-flipse))</del>

nope, subdomains are still in use, so no continues left!

Comment: That's going to cost a lot though, I'd imagine.

Comment: There's a bunch of things being hosted on the domain: http://james.gameover.com and http://rwc.gameover.com/forums/ are examples. Google 'site:gameover.com' to see everything.

Comment: nice find there!

Answer (score 7):

Lost in the Game.

## LostInTheGame.com

Available.

Comment: I think we're going to have to clean this question up, either by deleting negative answers, or creating a new question with less options. It's become a pain to browse through them all, and very few have positive votes. (commenting here to get some visibility)

Comment: @Juan Manuel: *workaround*: this [placeholder link](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/598#598) will find the page with the 0 vote answers (if sorting by votes -- but why not sort by newest anyway?)

Answer (score 6):

## AchievementUnlocked.com

Why play games for anything else? :P

It's expiring soon?
Bah! I don't know how to read those web WHOIS things! Might be available.

Comment: would there be any possibility of a trademark infringement claim by microsoft?

Comment: "Achievement" isn't trademarked by Microsoft, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Too localized to XBOX tho.

Comment: @Jblaske: http://armorgames.com/play/2893/achievement-unlocked ; the phrase is far from localized.

Comment: one flash game (albeit a great one) does not overpower the monster that is xbox live. I would venture to say that most people think of xbox when they hear that phrase.

Comment: I'm not arguing that microsoft didn't do it *first* but I question the notion that achievements themselves are synonymous with xbox live.

Comment: I think of Steam...

Answer (score 6):

## wasd.com

*(Domain parked)*

A PC gaming bias to the name, but we all know PC gaming is for true gamers.

Comment: It was okay until I read the justification :(

Comment: You're right the justification should read: "*A PC gaming bias to the name, but we all know true gamers are PC gamers.*"

Answer (score 6):

### 1337Answers.com

Not taken ([whois](http://www.whois.net/whois/1337answers.com)).  To be pronounced "*Leet* Answers"

Comment: As a reference: http://anyhub.net/file/tmpcf5b.png

Comment: clever, but not smooth enough.

Answer (score 6):

## ButtonMashers.com

Answer (score 6):

### onemorelevel.com

([3am] Ook one mooore level. Promise.)

Comment: +1 This me every night.

Answer (score 5):

**quickload.com** (squatted, but Joel says taken does not necessarily mean impossible: [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/))

as opposed to [quicksave.com](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/407#407)

Answer (score 5):

## flawlessvictory.com

It states it is for sale. While this originates from a specific game franchise, Mortal Kombat, I think it is sufficiently ingrained in gaming culture to be used more generically.

Answer (score 4):

## therightcastle.com

(available)

The princess is actually here!

Comment: Game specific, but awesome.

Comment: i think it's less game-specific and more cute-inside-joke

Comment: +15/-12... wow!

Comment: @alex I know :/

Answer (score 4):

## questoverload.com

(available)

You didn't sign up to figure out where the 12 chickens are! There are universes to save!

Comment: Spinoff of  [this other proposal](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/437#437) taking Noctrine's feedback.

Comment: +1, 4 characters made all the difference :P

Comment: This is a gaming site though, not an RPG site. Some people enjoy FPS/RTS :)

Comment: @Chris: You mean FPSes like Quake 4 don't come with a metric crapton of objectives?

Answer (score 3):

skiptutorial.com

Comment: Hehe, you skip the tutorial and instead come here and ask how to do something that's described in the tutorial?

Comment: ISkippedTheTutorial.com http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/420#420

Comment: Way too long. Skiptutorial.com is much more concise, or alternatively SkippedTutorial.com.

Comment: A tutorial that teaches you how to skip? Remember skip-its? My sister had one...

Answer (score 3):

nowloading.com

Too bad loadingscreen is taken.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to the current leading [Logo](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/logo-proposals-for-gaming) I thought of

### [SlidingPaddle.com](http://www.whois.net/whois/slidingpaddle.com)

Which is available

Comment: I like it, although "paddle" does have connotations for other interest groups too...

Answer (score 2):

GameOverdose.com (squatted)

It sounds like stack overflow without being a complete knockoff...

Comment: Great except its being squatted... http://www.whois.net/whois/gameoverdose.com

Comment: like it very much, way better than gameoverflow. gamINGoverdose seems to be in use too =(

Comment: Gah. I don't think it was squatted when I first suggested it, I'm pretty sure I checked... EDIT: apparently it was, according to the whois. Sorry!! I must've just checked that it went to a valid website...

Answer (score 2):

**SpawningPoint.com**

I think it also sounds very nice when spoken.

Comment: like it, although they're usually called "spawn points" not "spawning points"

Comment: @Kip: "spawnpoint.com" wasn't available anyway...

Answer (score 2):

**newgame.com** or even better **newgameplus.com** (damn I hate domain parkers)

**edit** in case you missed ChronoTrigger (shame on you! :p): [NewGame+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Game_Plus)

**edit** Joel says taken does not necessarily mean impossible: [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

Comment: If newgameplus was available, I'd vote for this +100 - it was like the first thing I thought of and it'd be perfect.

Comment: No idea what it means

Comment: @Joe New Game + is the mode that some RPGs have had where you would start a new game with all your levels and stuff, but with extra content, or some bonus.

Comment: @Joe sorry for not explaining, I edited in a wiki-link

Comment: @Corey Joel posted it might still be ok

Answer (score 1):

## savecorrupted.com

(or **filecorrupt**<s>ed</s>**.com** or **savecorrupt.com**)

Basically, a play on a corrupt save file. <s>Strikeout</s> indicating that there could be a -ed suffix if it sounds better.

Comment: i like savecorrupted.com

Answer (score 1):

### joystickguru.com

Available

Or any other smilar joystick variations?

Answer (score 0):

#### AfterPong.com

.

(because InsertCoin.com is already squatted on.)

Answer (score 0):

A lesson hard-learned:

### SaveEarlySaveOften.com

Looking around it seems people apply this advice to all sorts of things, but I always thought of it in terms of RPGs.

Comment: It's a bit too long for just a domainname.

Comment: 4 words. Too long.

Answer (score 0):

*placeholder*

**do not vote on this, this is a link to link to the 0 vote answers**

Comment: -1: placeholder.com is taken, and it's also not gaming related. (yes, that was a joke.)

Comment: @Kip: well, we *could* apply the guy.brush -> [Guybrush Threepwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guybrush_Threepwood) principle somehow...

Comment: sorry, maybe I'm slow, but what's the point of having "a link to link to the 0 vote answers"?

Comment: @Pop: Uhm, I wanted to leave a comment on the question explaining that, but either it got noise-flagged or I forgot (which is more likely...). The intention was being able to easily find suggestions that have not been voted on yet, whereas sorting by votes and jumping to the last site will jump to the downvoted ones.

Answer (score -1):

**RamDump.com** (available)

Because a "Ram Dump" is essentially what a saved game [file] is.

Comment: Too programmery, I'd say..

Answer (score -1):

## gamepier.com

Answer (score -1):

**answerguild.com** (available)

Comment: I'm not a fan of having the description of the sites purpose, QnA, in the name.

Comment: Me either. Abcdefg

Answer (score -1):

## gamehangs.com

Answer (score -1):

## CoinCommando.com

Answer (score -1):

I wish killscreen.com wasn't taken. Keeping with the problem/failure theme what about: (???)

### ScreenTearing.com

Answer (score -1):

## [gamingfailure.com](http://www.whois.net/whois/gamingfailure.com)

Comment: hmm... I don't like the word "failure", perhaps there's a reason it's available

Answer (score -1):

## oochelp.com

(out of character help, could use any twist on that with ooc)

Answer (score -1):

**SpritesGalore.com** (available)

Answer (score -1):

### minusworld.com

(Currently squatted and for sale, but according to [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) that's not necessarily a dealbreaker. Also I like the name a lot.)

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: It's a pretty famous bug in Super Mario Bros.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros.#The_Minus_World

Answer (score -1):

### omghelpme.com

(Currently taken by GoDaddy, for sale)

Answer (score -1):

UpDownLeftRight.com

Answer (score -1):

## telefraggd.com

(available!)

Answer (score -1):

**permakilled.com**

Answer (score -1):

## norespawn.com

Answer (score -1):

### ababselectstart.com

(Available!)

Comment: whois.com chokes on ↑↓↑↓←→←→abab↩▶.com :/

Answer (score -1):

## 99thlevel.com

For a pacman reference, 256thlevel.com is also available, but I think 99 is a nicer number..

Answer (score -1):

## SaveReload.com

I'm sure we've all done it at times.

Answer (score -1):

## bossdefeated.com

Comment: nice, and available

Answer (score -1):

doesmovingthecontrollerhelp.com

Answer (score -1):

**ISkippedTheTutorial.com**

Answer (score -1):

## losingisfun.com

(available)

Answer (score -1):

## sidequestoverload.com

(available)

You didn't sign up to figure out where the 12 chickens are! There are universes to save!

Comment: This is my first suggestion I actually like...

Comment: Motivation behind it is cool, I just feel like its a bit long.

Comment: @Noctrine: [What about questoverload.com then?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/446#446)

Comment: i actually like this better than questoverload.com

Answer (score -1):

### godmodeon.com

(Available)

Comment: Well, that's a problem nonetheless.

Comment: Changed it to godmodeon.com, which is a Quake reference and in all of its children as far as I know: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quake_-_family_tree.svg

Comment: i glanced at it and thought "what's a god modem?"

Answer (score -1):

## GameCompleted.com

It registered by GoDaddy, but is not reachable (DNS not resolved) so I cannot tell if it is used or squatted.

Answer (score -1):

## StackOfGames.com

(available)

Comment: Maybe GameStack, but I don't like the 'Of'.

Comment: I like it actually.  A nice visual.

Answer (score -1):

## lastlife.com

Squatted.

Answer (score -1):

### finitelives.com

Available

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/435#435

Answer (score -1):

## gamesperts.com

games + experts?  Also has the connotation of games + spurts, not sure if that's good or bad...

Answer (score -1):

## howtogame.com

.

Answer (score -1):

**hitanykeytocontinue.com**

we've all seen this,haven't we?

I've tried Press Any key first,wasn't available,also tried press any key to continue,also wasn't

Answer (score -1):

### allyourbase.com

Answer (score -1):

## BossFight.com

Although sadly [taken](http://www.whois.net/whois/bossfight.com):

```
Domain Name: BOSSFIGHT.COM
Registrar: DOMAINPEOPLE, INC.
Whois Server: whois.domainpeople.com
Referral URL: http://www.domainpeople.com
Name Server: NS0.SECUREPOD.COM
Name Server: NS1.SECUREPOD.COM
Status: ok
Updated Date: 26-feb-2010
Creation Date: 03-mar-2007
Expiration Date: 03-mar-2011
```

Answer (score -1):

### GameExperts.com

(Squated)

Answer (score -2):

## player-one.com

<sup>I was going to suggest player-two.com, but [playertwo.com](http://playertwo.com/) is taken.</sup>

Not available. (?)

Comment: i'd prefer it without the hyphen.

Comment: @alastair -- playerone.com is also free; so is player1. I'm not a fan of "playerone" because it reads funny in Italian :D

Answer (score -2):

manaburn.net

Answer (score -2):

**savinguniverses.com**

Because frankly, that's what you do in 99% of the games...

Answer (score -2):

## EpicSideQuest.com

The hardest part is finding a domain that isn't already taken. ;)

Answer (score -2):

### SunAverse.com

because serious gamers rarely see sunlight. And it kind of sounds like Universe.

Answer (score -2):

**anothercastle.com**

(sadly, it's already taken...)

Answer (score -2):

**<strike>daddeln.com</strike>** (taken)

Is there no english word for this? The German word [daddeln](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daddeln) means something like wildly hacking the controller

Comment: Button Mashing is the English term

Comment: @tzenes thanks. too bad buttonmasher.com is also already taken

Answer (score -2):

## 99percentcomplete.com

Because you're always trying to get that last percent.

Comment: Too lengthy and not obvious enough

Comment: I don't like domain names with numbers in them. Seems so... spammy, advertise-y. I don't know why.

Comment: @Corey: Me neither. I was just brainstorming and posting all the ones I find. Something will bubble to the top, right? Or at least inspire something better.

Answer (score -2):

Straightforward: gaminghelpers.com

Answer (score -2):

FragFAQ.com

....

Answer (score -2):

### RandomAchievement.com

Comment: I don't know about "random", but getting "achievement" in is interesting

Answer (score -2):

## respawnplz.com

Answer (score -2):

## guidedangit.com

[Gaming Trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GuideDangIt) and the behavior is what would drive users here.

Answer (score -2):

**HeroicCounsel.com**

Answer (score -2):

**<strike>ExtraBall.com</strike>** (unavailable)

Comment: sounds like a crazy fetish site...

Answer (score -2):

A bit silly, but it's probably worse than getting a stack overflow:

**InstaOwned.com**

Comment: I like it. But add **InstaPwned.com**, just in case...

Comment: @Tobias: it's your idea, add it yourself :)

Answer (score -2):

## startcommandos.com

Answer (score -2):

## sofaloafers.com

Answer (score -2):

## ShowConsole.com

A play on the PC gamer showing the console and game consoles.

Comment: But other gaming platforms are also the scope of this site

Answer (score -2):

**InstaPwned.com**

[instead of InstaOwned](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/273#273)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's not the best idea, just trying to get more ideas going. Keeping with the failure theme of StackOverflow and ServerFault, what about: (?)

### MissingNo.com

Its short for "Missing number", a glitch in the original Pokemon games. [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MissingNo.).

> ["MissingNo." appears] when the game attempts to access data for a nonexistent Pokémon species.

Eh, I'm tryin' here. A glitch/screw-up, but then it's also, eh hem, "what appears in the absence of any other data".

Answer (score -2):

### sociogamer.com

Available at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like Jack Thompson would love it.

Answer (score -2):

### howdoimovethepaddleinpong.com

[Another bad idea I had to put out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)

Answer (score -2):

## StackOfDoom.com

May be too TBS specific (or even civ specific), but just throwing out ideas.

Answer (score -2):

## wizardneedsfoodbadly.com

It's squatted but not really used, and Joel just said, I quote:

"(1) if the domain is actively being used for something legit, it's probably not for sale. Don't even suggest it.
(2) if the domain has a squatter on it, it's probably for sale. It may be super expensive or it may be $100. If you think it's a good domain, suggest it.
(3) When you vote, vote SOLELY based on what you think an awesome name would be, without regard to availability."

I'm just not sure how many people will get the gauntlet reference.

Comment: 4 words, too long IMO.

Answer (score -2):

Whereistheprincess.com

Answer (score -2):

throwstrategyguide[s]away.com

Answer (score -2):

## bossoverload.com

(available)

Answer (score -2):

GuidingCursor.com

free

Answer (score -2):

GuidingPointer.com

free

Answer (score -2):

IntPlus1.com

free

The idea is a play on equipment stats like "strength + 5" and since the site is about knowledge I thought "Intelligence" would be closest.

Comment: I think that would be better for the RPG proposal.  Maybe TomeOfIntelligence.com ...

Answer (score -2):

I really don't think most of these get to what the point of this site is.  We are the Hardcore Gamers who know the minor details of games.  We know where to find the hidden energy container in Megaman 7 in the Jungle Zone.  We know the optimal build for a Barbarian in Diablo 2 to maximize dps.

We need a name which expresses this: **HardcoreGamers**

Comment: but what about those casual gamers who have problems with Wii Sports Resort? I think this might alianate(sp?) some of our potential userbase (question askers.) =0 vote.

Answer (score -2):

[konamicode.com](http://www.whois.net/whois/konamicode.com) godaddy-ed, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code)

Comment: i think that would be trademark infringement

Answer (score -3):

Gamershelpmenu.com

Gamershelppack.com

Or something to do with navi

Like gamersheylisten.com

Answer (score -3):

theprincessisinanothercastle.com

*Maybe a little too long ;)*

Comment: I love the reference, but then it implies that the answers are on another site...

Comment: i just proposed simply anothercastle.com, but it looks like its taken (though nothing is there)...

Answer (score -3):

Why not

Theprincessisinthiscastle.com

?

Answer (score -3):

In continuation to my other answer:

**savinggalaxies.com**

(because that's what you do in 99% of the games... and its less syllables than  savinguniverses.com)

Comment: I kinda like it, It's not generic enough in my opinion. Implies Sci-Fi to me.

Comment: I like it a lot too. It's one of the only names that fit in with the common theme. That is, starting with an S and being two words.

Comment: The double 'g' is killing me (hey that rhymes!)

Answer (score -3):

**gamesoverflow.net**

Comment: Nothing personal at all, I just don't like it. StackOverflow is an error in programming. Need more diversity in naming. :)

Answer (score -3):

**GlobalThermonuclearWar.com**

Obviously nobody wants to type this but I thought it would be fun to add to the list

Comment: This sounds like a good name for a Q&A site for [DEFCON](http://www.introversion.co.uk/defcon/ "DEFCON") :)

Comment: A strange game. The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: How about a nice game of chess?

Comment: Would.you.like.to.play.a.game?  Love to.

Comment: I guess most of the younger folks have no idea what you are talking about... ;-)

Answer (score -3):

<strike>epicpixels.com</strike> (taken)

Comment: I can't seen if this squatted upon due to my corporate firewall.

Comment: it's taken: http://www.whois.net/whois/epicpixels.com

Comment: Dangnammit! I was hoping that it wasn't :(

Answer (score -3):

## SpawnKilled.net

Going with the whole "epic fail" thing of all the other trilogy sites, I would say spawnkilled, but sadly the .com domain is taken and the .net domain seems just a bit wrong..

But nevertheless, I propose spawnkilled.net

Comment: http://spawnfragged.com/ is not taken, however.

Answer (score -3):

**<strike>UpUpDownDown.com</strike>** (unavailable)

**LevelUpGet.com** (or similar, on a WoW theme)

Comment: Don't pigeon-hole it to WoW, the vast majority of gamers don't know too much of WoW terminology.

Answer (score -3):

Something along the lines with "Advice" (or a synonym of), as I believe its a great word for these sites, then perhaps somehow playing along with the words "Guild" or "Clan". Some combination along those lines, create the community and give it a name.

Gamers are used to "clans" and "guilds", and belonging to one of the largest in existence (this site), across all games, where their reputation is merited based on their video game knowledge, has quite the selling point amongst the target audience.

clanofadvice.com (I don't like it, it's an idea for the theme though)

I also am squatting on **AdviceAlliance.com** right now, which I would be willing to donate/whatever for this site.

Any ideas? Any more "fun" words that we could use?

Comment: Can't we just steal your Epic Adivce @Jesta ;-)

Comment: actually, a bad idea to assume cans/guilds, as this might limit the potential audience (clans/guilds are multiplayer only)

Answer (score -3):

**GameStack.com**

A subtle nod to the "Stack"...

gamestack.org and thegamestack.com are registered, but don't seem to be high-profile sites.

Comment: That's an idea, but "stack" really doesn't have anything to do with gaming. Nothing personal, of course.

Comment: A stack of games is not an uncommon sight, to be fair...

Comment: I've got more than one stack of games...  :)

Answer (score -3):

Merging my previous answer with some other answers:

**SavingPrincesses.com**

Answer (score -3):

mycontrollersbroken.com

http://brokencontroller.com is taken, but only states `WOW IT SURE IS BROKEN ISNT IT?`

Answer (score -3):

**pauseforsoda.com** (available)

Answer (score -3):

## GameGems.com

Not being squatted, but currently taken. Probably could be bought.

Comment: how do you know the difference between a squatted domain and a taken-but-not-squatted domain?

Answer (score -3):

gamelikeapro.com

Answer (score -3):

**UpMyStats.com**

Answer (score -3):

**HeroicAid.com**

Answer (score -3):

**PressStartToContinue.com?** (it's free)

Comment: Also a bit long. I'd hate to have to type that in every time.

Comment: @Alastair: may I suggest moving to a browser with bookmarks? :P (just kidding, it's a bit long in my opinion as well)

Answer (score -3):

**cartridgeoverblow.com**

Alternatively, **cartoverblow.com**, which is shorter.

Answer (score -3):

## helpofholding.com

(like bag of holding, an endless bag, this is endless help with a game reference)

Answer (score -3):

### uberAnswers.com

Answer (score -3):

## clickherenottodie.com

(available)

A nod at Yahtzee's pet peeve.

Answer (score -3):

### askordie.com

(available)

Answer (score -3):

## level998.com

(available)

Comment: Because the level before the last level is always the hardest...

Answer (score -3):

### [Stage22.com](http://www.whois.net/whois/Stage22.com)

(parked by GoDaddy)

The stage at which the fabled [Donkey Kong kill screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_screen#Donkey_Kong) occurs.

Comment: It's actually not parked by GoDaddy, it's registered by `Kurt Varner`.

Answer (score -3):

### [Stage256.com](http://www.whois.net/whois/Stage256.com)

(available)

The stage at which the fabled [Pac-Man kill screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_screen#Pac-Man) occurs.

Answer (score -3):

## **gameoverflow.com**

Or did someone say that? It has a squatter though.

Answer (score -3):

hoeofdestruction.com

Too obscure for many gamers (it's a not easily found weapon in Ultima 7), but I wanted to point out that the Hoe of Destruction is in fact awesome.

Comment: *resists jokes about the hoe of destruction*

Answer (score -3):

what about **savestate.com**?

Comment: It somewhat lends itself for people to think this is a site for emulation.

Answer (score -3):

GameDiskStack.com

free

Answer (score -3):

GameCdStack.com

free

Answer (score -3):

StackOGames.com

Stack o' Games - free

Answer (score -3):

### joystickoverflow.com

Available

Play on StackOverflow, anyone?

Answer (score -4):

WalkthroughQnA.com

Comment: walk-through/guide questions are being (questionably) moderately down-voted, so this doesn't fit the current atmosphere of the site.

Comment: Agreed, plus the QnA looks silly.

Answer (score -4):

expertdexchange.com

(ask nicely and you can also change str and int!)

Comment: It's really funny as an insider joke, but probably not that good for promoting the website.

Comment: I know, I just had to put it out :D

Answer (score -4):

## ↑↓↑↓←→←→abab↩▶.com

#### a.k.a. XN--ABAB-FT8AAFAKBGB80AS41C.COM

Available!

Comment: "I heard it on XN minus minus ABAB dash garbage dot com!"

Comment: Oh that's good.  I was worried such a simple and obvious name would have been taken.

Comment: awesome! but I'm afraid I'd pass on a tinyurl then...

Comment: -1, controller buttons use capital letters.

Answer (score -5):

## notyouraveragegamingquestionandanswersite.com

Available - 18:01 July 16 2010

Comment: Seems excessive!

Answer (score -5):

**Game0ver.com**

---

```
   Domain Name: GAME0VER.COM
   Registrar: ENOM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.enom.com
   Referral URL: http://www.enom.com
   Name Server: NS.RACKSPACE.COM
   Name Server: NS2.RACKSPACE.COM
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Updated Date: 02-sep-2009
   Creation Date: 13-sep-2001
   Expiration Date: 13-sep-2010
```

Comment: What makes you think they won't extend it? :\

Comment: l33tspeek? dunno... seems to easy to be confused with gameover.com

Comment: I thought that was an O at first, and will probably be extended.. considering it's been held since 2001.

Comment: Leetspeek urls are difficult to promote. Many people will misread and go to gameover.com instead.

Answer (score -6):

**updownleftrightybxa.com**

May appeal more to the slightly older generation...