# Logo proposals for Gaming

Tags: discussion, top-7, logo

Please post as answers below, your logo proposals for this site.

**Rules:**

- Original artwork only.
- You need to have a copy of your submission in a vector format.

[Return to Site Attributes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/site-attributes)

Comment: this should be CW i think

Comment: Why? On this Meta, nobody gets points for stuff anyway.

Comment: CW makes it easier to access for editing, which can be very useful for a utility question like this. It also keeps the format identical with the rest of the [Site Attributes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41/site-attributes) (which would be nice to add as a link in your question body).

Comment: Can you really choose a logo before picking one name and sticking with it?

Comment: @badp - possibly, some logos are universal while others do refer to the name.

Comment: @George Edison: When asking users to contribute to a list of answers, the question should be marked community wiki. It has little to do with "getting points."

Answer (score 24):

Here's a version of the [other](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/logo-proposals-for-gaming/664#664) with a longer left leg (as suggested by EricSchaefer) and one with the longer left leg and a thicker paddle (as suggested by DavRob60):

[image: Gaming.se]

[image: Gaming.se]

I have an idea for the text that I want to try, but I have to find a font for it first.  Let me know what you think about these (whether you like the longer leg or the thicker paddle) and I'll see what I can do about finding a font for my other idea.

Comment: I really like it!

Comment: Do you have a preference for the thinner paddle or the thicker paddle?

Comment: I prefer the thicker paddle.

Comment: Looks really good (thicker paddle)!

Comment: +1 for this one.

Comment: Upvote @DavRob60 thicker paddle comment (in addition to this answer) if you really like the thicker paddle version.

Comment: (I prefer the small paddle version.)

Comment: Another one for the small paddle. (Upvote @alexanderpas if you prefer that)

Answer (score 15):

First, I really like the Stack Overflow logo. it's small, it's square...

So I thought of something inspired of pong, but my graphical talent are somewhat limited.

The "paddle" should then be in the bottom and a ball "bounce" like the stack element of the Stack Overflow logo. We could also add a trail to the ball.

**Update :** I made a quick concept image. It's not vectorial, the color are is not exactly what I want and the alignment of the balls is off. So it should be redone by someone with *real* graphical skill. But the idea is there. 
The balls trail may also be replaced with a curved doted line...

[image: concept]

and here Michael Herold concept.

[image]

Comment: I like the concept, but the image looks like a checkmark

Comment: I modified your concept a little bit. Since the original Pong did straight reflection of the shot, I did away with the curve in the line. Also, I went with a square as the "ball", since that's what the original Pong had. I made it look like SO logo, just for fun and to see what it might look like. [It's hosted here](http://img409.imageshack.us/img409/4830/mocksogaming.png) on ImageShack.

Comment: thanks, I edited it to include your concept.

Comment: @Juan Manuel, I agree.

Comment: You should turn it -90 degrees so that it actually looks like Pong, I never played Pong vertically...

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: true, but I turn it +90 in the first concept so it is more alike StackOverflow's logo. It have the advantage that it also recall the brick breaker style games.

Comment: I like @Michael's!

Comment: Upvote the previous comment (in addition to this answer) if you really like @Michael's version.

Comment: and don't rotate it anymore, this way it is both applicable for [pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) (when viewed from [cocktail cabinet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcade_cabinet#Cocktail_or_table_cabinets) position.) and [arkanoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkanoid) / [breakout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_%28arcade_game%29).

Comment: I like the idea, but it looks like an arrow. Maybe if the left leg would be a little longer?

Comment: @EricShaefer - I'll try that this afternoon. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @EricSchaefer - I fear it will look like a checkmark then (see Juan Manuel's first comment)

Comment: @DavRob60 left leg, not right

Comment: @EricSchaefer - Then it will look like a checkmark when viewed from a mirror ;-P... Seriously, I think it's a good idea. that way the hit point could be a bit offset from the middle of the paddle.

Comment: I also suggest to make that paddle thicker.

Comment: I'm going to make a new answer to show what it looks like with a longer "left leg".

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking of doing something along the lines of an alien from Space Invaders, but then realized that is the Video Games Live logo.

What other old games are there that have a well-known trope?

**Edit**: As per DavRob60's comment, here's a mockup of a logo with the Space Invaders ship.  I thought I'd add it to this answer, but if we want this answer to be a discussion for my question, I can post it in another answer.

[image: Space Invaders mockup of gaming.se]

Comment: Instead of the alien, we may use the user controlled a laser  cannon?

Comment: no offense, but that made me instantly think of an unmentionable first :-p.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too.  But I took "exact" measurements of the laser cannon and that's what it would look like ... O.o

Comment: To me it looks like a broken joystick or toilet plunger...

Comment: I like it, and we could pretty much use the original sprite as an icon version!

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm with @Mechko here... that looks way too pornographic...

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of using a simple retro gaming style icon - the Pong and Space Invaders are good ones. In a similar vein...

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm sure someone more arty than myself could make more suitable versions!

Comment: +1 for the tetris logo... the pac-man logo probably wouldn't work--it clearly infringes on the pac-man trademark

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of a joystick. Maybe a joystick placed in front of a screen? That could be rendered quite stylistically to keep it similar to the stackoverflow logo.

Answer (score -2):

My idea is basically a finger frantically pressing a button again and again.

First draft:

[image: finger pressing a button repeatedly]

I'll try to make it a bit more stylish, help from others will be welcome.

Comment: I like how it somewhat echoes the Stack Overflow logo...

Comment: Same, but I'm not sure how well it'd fit with a logo. Maybe try making a logo-esque design with some filler text?

Comment: Like the concept, not the actual design though.

Comment: that would be great for buttonmasher.com

Comment: Pressing a button is representative of any computer-related task, but not necessarily related to videogames. 

I would suggest to look for a more representative icon in the pop culture, something that nearly anyone in the world can unmistakably associate with playing videogames.

Comment: @Auron: other than gaming (and maybe the stock market?), I don't know of any activity which requires repetitive, **frantic** button-pressing, which is what I was trying to convey here. Maybe it needs to be more frantic :)

Comment: I like it, but it seems to be too tall?  Most logos are roughly square, and I think ours should be too.

Comment: @C. Ross I planned on refining it if it gets enough votes... but so far it doesn't seem to be that popular.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, it stinks of facebook grinding games...

Answer (score -3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for quicksave.com

Comment: I know it's not very creative, but I just couldn't resist... Maybe consider it as inspiration :7

Comment: what about ctrl-f5?

Comment: @Juan Manuel: yes, definitely better :p

Comment: I thought it was just F10 in Half-Life

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: F5 in Morrwind and some other games, too. It's only bad when you're used to it and another game asigns it to quickload - and you hit it just after you *finally* finished that tough boss...

Comment: This is kinda exclusive to the PC gamers...

Comment: The KoToR games have F4 as quick save, and F5 as quick load!

Comment: @GAThrawn: I'd "d'oh" a lot then, after playing Morrowind for so long...

Answer (score -5):

[image]

Comment: Please don't downvote without an explanation!

Comment: I don't get how this relates to video games

Comment: @Earlz It is an input device consisting of a stick that pivots on a base and reports its angle or direction to the device it is controlling. It is often used to control video games, and usually has one or more push-buttons whose state can also be read by the device it is controlling. [more...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joystick)

Comment: @alexanderpas: +1! @Earlz: compliments! :D

Answer (score -10):

[image]

Comment: Someone want to explain the downvotes...?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it resembles the PS3 controller too much (note: the buttons are actually XBOX like).

Comment: @George: too bland.

Comment: A suggestion for improvement would go a long way...

Comment: Way too dark, thought that was a moustache at first glance!

Comment: @GAThrawn: you mean [*the* mustache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario)?