# Last Chance -- Top domain name: pauseforhelp.com. Speak now or forever hold your peace.

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name gaming.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

[Jin](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) is ready to start working on your logo so we need to finalize the site name choice.

The top-voted choice, quicksave.com, is *not* for sale. The only viable candidate is "Pause for Help" (pauseforhelp.com), which we are currently holding.

If anyone has any awesome, last-minute brainstorming suggestions, **now is the time to suggest it.** Please don't repeat [choices from the last thread](http://pastebin.com/7qY5HxH5). We need fresh ideas.

This is a **great site** for rapid-fire brainstorming of domain names: [**Instant Domain Search**](http://instantdomainsearch.com/)

We are shotgunning suggestions **[in our gaming room.](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/domain-name)**

### Note on Eligibility:

This is *not* about speculating on domains. After 2-1/2 months of selection and voting, it's time to make a choice. If you wish to suggest parked domains, **you need to request *and list* the price first.** Thank you.

Comment: what about "that one level", or "infinite lives"?

Comment: +1 because I like "Pause for Help."

Comment: I like that one level better than pause for help, can't we get a vote on those 2 possibilities? perhaps adding them as answers to this question?

Comment: +1 Go with PauseForHelp.com

Comment: For now I'm leaning towards "Pause for Help" because it conveys the gaming theme(pausing the game) and assitance. After all, our gaming site is where people get quality answers. But I welcome any new ideas.

Comment: +1 for importance, but I dislike pauseforhelp.com, see answer.

Comment: I'm with Pause For Help. That said, both it and That One Level (Personally, I'd prefer something like "Stage One" and make us less about tropes, but I had my chance before) work excellently with the font that Jin has been showing off as a title, so I don't mind which one is selected.

Comment: ok, fair enough; I'm not that in love with That One Level, Pause for Helps is good also.

Comment: @Grace, stageone.com is taken but world1-1.com isn't.

Comment: @Grace "Stage One" is definitely cooler, but I think we're out voted

Comment: @badp Technically, my preference is Stage Six (which has a history for me, what with STAGE SIX RAGE, in addition to being the traditional "final stage"), but that too was also an old site (albeit they died).

Comment: @Juan Manuel: No response on Infinite Lives. And everyone--absolutely everyone--that I market-tested "That One Level" on hated it. So I went with this communities *highest* voted choice, "Pause for Help." **I was hoping to hear some *better* suggestions here.** We *should* be able to do better.

Comment: @Robert, fair enough (that's why I deleted the post)

Comment: What exactly is our timetable on this? 1 day? 3? Of course sooner is better. The site beta period ends in 18 days (10/5?) so it can't be long anyway... I'll be desperately trying to come up with anything better for as long as we have.

Comment: @WillfulWizard: Don't know. The longer we don't have a name, the *less* time Jin will have to work on finalizing the design. I'm still hoping someone will have an epiphany that will be met with a resounding "eureka!"

Comment: PauseForHelp? Worst name on the list IMO.

Comment: This question has had a total of 45 answer upvotes and 37 answer downvotes...

Comment: @badp indeed. So much negativity.

Comment: I wish the names would hold some gaming culture feel to it. For example, 1up.com. GamingOwls? PauseForHelp?

Comment: QuickSave is an awesome idea, what a shame it's taken. A couple of thoughts; Something regarding those Help Line toll phone numbers that used to be in gaming instruction manuals? helpline.com is taken, strategyguide.com is taken (surprise), 1up.c... never mind. I don't have a good wit for coming up with snappy words for something like this. God knows I'm anything but terse.

Comment: Oh oh oh oh I got it. iwannabetheguythegamethehelpsite.com ... no? Ok ok, fine.

Comment: The amount of disagreement in this thread is stunning. Most of these 0's and -1's have 10+ votes in either direction. "Gaming.SE: We hate ourselves and want obscurity."

Comment: I don't like "PauseForHelp.com"

Comment: I don't like pauseforhelp.com at all. I like Juan's infinite lives suggestion, as well as a few of the answers below, which I voted for.

Comment: All the names in both threads are awful... I think the problem with finding a good name for a gaming site is that gaming is **huge** on the web, so everything good is taken. I thought QuickSave was a great name but we can't even use it.

Comment: Robert, maybe you just need to make an executive decision and pick what you, as a PR man, think is the best. I somehow feel we are not qualified enough... also I would suggest looking not only on the total number of votes, but also on the upvote/downvote ratio.

Comment: LearnToPlay.com - or follow concept. go!

Comment: Does it have to be a .com address, or can it be a .org or the like?

Comment: @Powerlord: .com is *hugely* preferred, especially in for a nonacademically-inclined site. When the .com is already taken (and we settle for the the .org), all we are doing is feeding traffic to another site and confusion the users.

Comment: `GiantEnemyCrab.com` is taken. Sigh. `MassiveDamage.com` is taken. `Critical`(`Hit`|`Damage`)`.com` is taken. This is a hard one. Hmmm. `ItalianPlumbers.com` is available... Not that these are ingrained historical excellent choices for names, though.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I think that's just an extension of "I can vote up once for the one I like, and downvote everything else on principle because it's meta, and there's no reason to *not* downvote." I imagine a poll would have a much tighter spread (as well as no downvotes).

Comment: @Robert just out of curiosity, *whom* did you market-test thatonelevel.com on?

Comment: A link to the original question, since no one else was kind enough to post it: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site-closed  *(I see now it's also linked on the side of the page)* Personally, I like a lot of them from that thread, but don't like the highest-voted ones in this thread.  It should be noted also that stackexchange is really **REALLY** terrible for doing polls, so the highest-voted answers don't necessarily (or at all) represent the opinion of the community.

Comment: A name should sound well when saying: "I actually don't know. try asking on <Insert domain without the .com here>" ;)

Comment: May I suggest that if there is no clear consensus, that the "90 day review" does not pass, and instead we get an extension with the point of solidifying a name?

Comment: @VxJasonxV - I'm starting to think that a site *should* have its original sub-domain until which time they can come up with something demonstrably better. I suggested this very recently. We'll see how well it is received.

Comment: Since we're probably not getting a TLD for a while anyway, we might as well have quicksave.stackexchange.com too, no?

Comment: @Robert: I agree. @Tobias: Why would we need two names? That's more confusing simply because QuickSave will likely NOT be the name of the site, due to not being able to get the domain.

Comment: This thread has a large number of comments, and this one will probably get overlooked, but I think the idea of domain name is still an important one, outside of the elevator pitch, and that this thread should remain open, if only for the day when we have the traffic to justify our own domain name.  What's more `AskUbuntu` go their own domain name, so such a day is not beyond our reach.

Answer (score 16):

## Boss-Level

is also available, (and works as a double-meaning-- the place where bosses, us, the experts, hang out) but I was afraid to suggest it on account of the hyphen (as bosslevel *is* taken (but then again, has copyright 2001, so it might be for sale)).

is available through GoDaddy (either 7.49 (with a coupon? Unsure how this instant site-finder works...) or 11.99, same as all the other ones through GoDaddy).

(Those looking for **OneMoreBoss** can find it as [a separate answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance/1077#1077). If you previously voted based on **OneMoreBoss** please revise your vote on this answer)

Comment: -1 it sounds too much like a hype name

Comment: Neutral on this one. Doesn't have the same pop as Stage Six/Seven.

Comment: For the record, I'm more partial to Boss-Level than OneMoreBoss; So I wonder -- what are our thoughts on hyphens? Unacceptable?

Comment: I like Boss-Level more as well - I rarely think of "One More Boss" as often as "One More Level" or "Finish This Level". As far as hyphens, I'm neutral but I know full well that many people dislike having to remember a hyphen.

Comment: By the way, when you upvote this proposal which _one_ domain are you supporting?

Comment: My fault. I'll split them into a separate answer. The question will be edited, so y'all can redistribute your votes appropriately.

Comment: @Arda Just like people causing stack overflows are a small percentage of SO's userbase.

Comment: @Arda Xi -- the word "boss" isn't exclusive to gaming. It also has the connotation of "expert", which fits the theme of the stack exchange sites quite well.

Comment: @Arda are you suggesting that most (or even some) gamers don't know what Bosses are? or Boss Levels?

Comment: @tzenes - Yes, I am.

Comment: @Arda I think you are sadly mistaken if you think that Gamers do not associate the term 'Boss level' with gaming.  I would go so far as to say "Better than 90% of gamers will recognize the phrase 'Boss Level' as gaming related"

Comment: How does boss level apply to a game like Starcraft 2?

Comment: aww, I had *the* idea: `bosskey.com` but it's taken and probably not for sale :(

Comment: @Doug -- two words: Terra-Tron

Comment: @Doug I don't want to spoil the ending for those who haven't played, but there is definitely a `Boss Level` in the Starcraft 2 Campaign.  But I think you're missing the point.  The point isn't that every game has a boss level (there are some that don't), the point is that gamers know what `Boss Level` means and to them it means something video game related.  Not every Programming question is about a `Stackoverflow` but the term means programming to every programmer.

Comment: @arda you've said as much before. Now obvious I and others disagree. If you want us to take it seriously them youre going to have to provide some really solid evidence that most english speaking gamers don't associate 'boss level' with gaming.

Comment: @Arda bold claims require evidence.  The word `most` came from my post to which you replied `yes`, but even if its a significant minority you're going to need evidence to back this claim up.  A Boss Level is definitely a gaming concept, if I Google the term " [Boss Level](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA347CA347&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Boss+Level#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA347CA347&q=%22boss+level%22&aq=f&aqi=g-c4g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=8d9c50a61d5b9175 "google")" I get games, gaming, and a band who's logo has an NES controller in it.

Comment: Now I'm not saying its unprovable but if you don't have evidence for your assertion then you can't reasonably expect us to acquiesce.

Comment: @tzenes We both know that 99% of the people ask for help on the gameplay helps in multiplayer rather than the campaign portion in SC2.

Comment: @Doug at the risk of repeating myself: I think the idea that the title has to be inclusive to all game is a bit inane. SO isn't just about Stackoverflows, or even just about utilizing the Stack, its about programming and Stackoverflow screams programming to programmers. Boss Level screams gaming to gamers. We need to be focusing less on an "inclusive" name, and more on good branding. In this case, that means a name which reminds you of gaming.

Comment: Small problem: bosslevel.com (without the "-") is taken and is not related to the topic at all. I think the two would be easily confused.

Answer (score 7):

## GamingOwls.com

Available.

Night owls. Wise gamers.

> I don't know... GamingOwls.com; It hit me right off as cool, easy to spell, easy to remember, easy to theme, and even apt. -- [Robert Cartaino](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/189798)

Comment: -1 it makes me think of old ladies who play DS... and Robert Cartaino liked it, which is an automatic -1. =)

Comment: I have never heard gowl as a word for genitalia, and I'm in Ireland. It's either regional, or uncommon.

Comment: The idea of owls (night time) also nicely fits into our current dark theme in my opinion.

Comment: Upvoting not because it's awesome, but because it's better than pauseforhelp.com in my opinion.

Comment: If we go with that, some pixelised owls should be added to the design...

Answer (score 6):

## dungeonmap.com

Of all the ones I've been throwing out there I really think this has potential. Especially given the double entendre that this site could serve as a dungeon map for stuck gamers.

Comment: I can't decide if it makes me think Legend of Zelda or Dungeons and Dragons more.

Answer (score 4):

Gonna toss this one out because I might as well.

## savemyprincess.com

She's available.

Comment: Not a fan, but +1 just for " __She's__ available."

Answer (score 4):

## HeartGaming.com

To go with the newest logo courtesty of Jin.

*Credit to Robert Cartaino♦ from this question: [Logo for Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/logo-for-gaming)

Comment: I would very much like something with the word *love* in it

Comment: "Boss-Love-l" ? ;P

Answer (score 3):

**8bitheroes.com**

Or variations on the bit/hero theme like:

**8bithero.com**

**bitwisehero.com** (as in bitwise and wise to things involving bits.)

We're not focused on 8-bit games of course, but I think that will be obvious to people visiting the site. And retro gaming has a place in modern gamer culture, a la t-shirts with space invaders.

(Everything I've tried in this theme is available.)

Comment: i think this would give the impression that the site is dedicated to retro gaming

Comment: sounds too much as a game specific site for 3D Dot Game Heroes

Comment: @Alexander really? I wouldn't associate the two, especially considering 3D Dot Heroes isn't 8 bit.

Comment: @Kip I think the idea that the title has to be inclusive to all game is a bit inane.  SO isn't just about Stackoverflows, or even just about utilizing the Stack, its about programming and Stackoverflow screams programming to programmers.  8 Bit Heroes screams gaming to gamers.  We need to be focusing less on an "inclusive" name, and more on good branding.  In this case, that means a name which reminds you of gaming.

Comment: I can agree with that.

Comment: I really like 8BitHero.

Comment: @tzenes- "8 bit heroes" screams "retro gaming" to me, not "gaming".

Comment: @Kip to give you basic brand analysis: Strong brands win over specific brands.  This is why the brand "Grandma's Cookies" sells, while, "Women in their 80s Cookies" doesn't.  Even though the picture maybe of a woman in her 80s, brand recognition of `Grandma` trumps it as the stronger brand.  I shouldn't have to explain why `Gaming` is a stronger brand than `Retro Gaming`.

Comment: @tzenes: exactly. so i guess you agree with me now?

Comment: @Kip I think you're missing my point.  `Gaming` is stronger than `Retro Gaming`, so people will associate `8 bit Heroes` with `Gaming` before they associate it with `Retro Gaming`.  This is marketing 101.

Answer (score 3):

**GameTamers.com**

We can help you tame your games.

It is available from GoDaddy according to the Domain Name Search

Answer (score 2):

**Level-Up.com**

Currently being parked and accepting offers for purchase. LevelUp.com is a Spanish gaming site, and is not available.

Comment: levelup.com levelupyourgame.net etc.

Answer (score 2):

### highlevelanswers.com

Plays on our Q&A concept.

Comment: doesn't portray gaming focus enough IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

### GamingFortress.com

Available.

We have a [bit of a history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) involving [castles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63745/badges-should-be-ordered-alphabetically/63816#63816). But I figure, I'll try out a simplistic suggestion that just focuses more on being explicit about us being a gaming site. Because, when I think about it, sites like "GameFAQs" and "RPGamer" and "Hardcore Gaming 101" have been pretty successful.

And at the end of the day, a fortress is just *another castle*.

Answer (score 2):

Is the less than sign even a valid choice for URLs?

## I<3Gaming.com

or

## We<3Gaming.com

are both open, standard prices via godaddy.

Not sure whether "I" or "We" works better.

*Credit to Tobias Kienzler

Comment: Maybe just spell out "heart"? I could see that being annoying, although I love the general idea.

Comment: @Ullallulloo -- both URLS with "heart" spelled out are taken. WeHeartGaming.com actually looks like some sort of gaming clan. They've even got a heart-logo that looks nigh identical to that which Jin put up.

Answer (score 1):

## lavajumping.com

Not taken at all, common in many games [and yet impossible in "real life".](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConvectionSchmonvection)

Try [googling "can you jump over lava?"](http://www.google.com/search?q=can+you+jump+over+lava%3F) -- *all* the hits are about gaming.

On a similar vein:

### slimepools.com

### spikedpits.com

### walkingmushrooms.com

### instadeath.com

### everythingkillsyou.com

### lowhitpoints.com

None of these are taken.

> **Warning!**
>
> By upvoting this answer you support **lavajumping.com**; by downvoting this answer you dislike **lavajumping.com**.
>
> If you would instead like to vote on one of the alternatives, please make a separate answer for it.
>
> <sub>PS: This edit allows you to change your vote for this answer.</sub>

Comment: walking mushrooms... lol; different audience IMO

Comment: I love spikedpits.com :)

Comment: Some of these are neato-keeno... but will be very weird if we don't update our site design to reflect it.

Comment: @Grace Design is the very reason why we need a name _now_

Comment: Point taken. [ ](http://o/~)

Comment: On that newest entry, I thought about other options besides just HP, but stopped after I thought of lowlife.com...

Comment: +1 for everythingkillsyou.com

Comment: @ixtmixilix like he said, if you like one of the others add that as an answer.  This is just voting for lavajumping

Answer (score 1):

## AnswerFarming.com

Available.

Answer (score 0):

**Ragequit**.com

Taken, unfortunately, but it does look like that domain might be sold for a dime. The website is broken, dead and hasn't been updated in 2 years.

Comment: +1 Hahaha I like it. Funny to watch.

Answer (score 0):

## killedbyagrue.com

or

## killedbygrue.com

Comment: As great of an idea as this is, it's too classic for the new kids here :). I mean, honestly, look at the suite of questions. Civ, Dwarf Fortress (which arguably shares fans with rogue-likes), Starcraft 2? Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

### 255lives.com

Available.

Comment: Why 255? Why not any other number?

Comment: It was often the number of lives that old games were hacked to have by cheat programs. This is because 255 is the highest number that can be represented by a single byte, so it was just a matter of changing the value of the byte which represented "number of lives".

Answer (score 0):

### gamingstack.com

Available, and plays on the immense popularity of stackoverflow and the "stackexchange" brand. We already have visits from Google with people searching for "gaming stack exchange" or "gaming stack", might as well go with it.

Comment: those were probaly lazy googlers

Answer (score 0):

## PlayerTested.com

Available.

Answer (score -1):

**clicktoreload.com**

not taken,will cost about 8 bucks on godaddy

Comment: and for the older crowd: **shootawayfromtheTVtoreload.com** ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**justonemoreminute.com**

... because that's what a good game makes you think at 3am...

also, the shorter **onemoreminute.com**,
both available

Answer (score -1):

**insertdisc2.com**

available

Comment: I actually like this. This or some idea like it might not be such a bad idea. disc-two.com is open, but that's kind of a hard form to remember.

Answer (score -1):

### TripleDamage.com

Available. Not very creative but better than "pauseforhelp.com", in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

## 30extra.com

as in, lives

Comment: I like this one. It flows smoothly, and extends are nice.

Answer (score -1):

## flagjump.com

.

Answer (score -1):

## redrupees.com

Answer (score -1):

After reading [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/time-is-up-what-is-our-domain-name-finally)

> In 85 days we cast 1,450 votes on 235
>   different domain names and we still
>   don't have a clear winner.

I suggest:

### TheGamingSiteWithNoName.com

Answer (score -1):

Concerning the possible shift in direction regarding the [WebApps v. Nothing To Install Debate](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com) I figure this one should come to a vote too:

### gaming.stackexchange.com

Available :>

Comment: The funny thing is, this is our site name.

Answer (score -1):

## GoodGameRe.com

Available.

Comment: What does the Re stand for, exactly?

Comment: restart! "gg re!"

Answer (score -2):

## **OneMoreBoss**

is available through GoDaddy (either 7.49 (with a coupon? Unsure how this instant site-finder works...) or 11.99, same as all the other ones through GoDaddy).

Seeks to invoke the feeling of a good game, as in, "I'll go to bed after OneMoreBoss"

Answer (score -2):

DontReset.com

available

kind of like "don't give up" ?

Answer (score -2):

replaylevel.com

free

Answer (score -2):

## ExperiencedPoints.com

Currently availiable.

Comment: The sole existence of the `d` in this name makes it a nightmare to give out. "experienced" isn't in the lingo, where "experience" is, obviously the problem is `ExperiencePoints.com` is undoubtedly taken. I can't agree with this one, though. One little letter makes all the difference in the world.

Answer (score -2):

A bit gruesome, but funny:

### EnableGibs.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

## youhavedysentery.com

Comment: ........lolwut?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: Oregon Trail

Answer (score -2):

## onemoresavepoint.com

Comment: too bad savepoint.com is taken

Answer (score -2):

## zoraflippers.com

Answer (score -2):

## wheresthesavepoint.com

Answer (score -2):

## standinfire.com

A favorite WoW past-time, also relevant in any game where standing in fire is a **bad thing**. e.g. life

Comment: Fire is a bad thing? Nintendo's most valuable advice has been "IF ALL ELSE FAILS USE FIRE".

Answer (score -2):

### notreallycheating.com

Asking questions isn't *really* cheating.

Available, Go Daddy $7.50

Answer (score -2):

## GameDetectives.com

Free.

Comment: Go Go Game Beating Answer.. (think Inspector Gadget)

Answer (score -2):

spoilerzone.com

available

Comment: Not really true though

Comment: @Juan I know, but neither would be "spoilerfree.com"... I'm still for thatonelevel

Answer (score -2):

## 8BitIlluminati

Experts since the dawn of gaming

Available through GoDaddy at standard rates.

Comment: Il-lum-what? three L next to eachother, and a difficult word.

Comment: It isn't three "l"s. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati

Answer (score -3):

GamingLords.com

available.

Answer (score -3):

Gametopia.com

available.

Answer (score -3):

Here's an alternative angle that I've been trying. Hah, angle. I didn't even mean that. In any case...

### Sleight Shot (sleightshot.com)

Available.

There's been a fair measure of support behind [one of our logo proposals](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/logo-proposals-for-gaming/699#699), namely that of a ball deflecting off of a paddle. While it is intended to represent something like Pong, I also look at it from the perspective of trick shots, reflections, and other demonstrations of cool sleight.

I started off with thinking about terminology for crazy maneuvers of skill. The intent is to convey the imagery that we're a place that harbours skill - tricky shots and maneuvers are not only interesting to see, but also fun to learn. I think it's an excellent imagery to show us off as a source of expert info.

All the easy, quick things like "skillshot", "trickshot", "angleshot", and "bankshot" (although **bank-shot.com** is available for $544, which is [posted separately here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance-top-domain-name-pauseforhelp-com-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your/1091#1091)) are all taken, but not this one. While it is a bit of high vocabulary, I do like the single-syllable nature of both words, and the alliteration.

This is technically reverse from your standard process, in which you devise a logo based on the title. But I found this to be an opportunistic window which to give another shot.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that we're going to use that logo (although I have voted for it). Rather, I simply used it as the source of inspiration for this perspective of thinking of domain names. I imagine that if we did go with this or bank-shot, that we'd need a logo with more *ping* and less Pong.

Comment: While I like this, I worry about the phonetic of SleightShot.com being just odd enough to make it a tough domain to find.

Comment: @LessPop The fact it's pronounced identical to SlightShot doesn't help much either. On the same vein of what I was going for, I also thought about wall jumping, which is present across a lot of games in many genres and varies between a basic and necessary skill to an advanced technique that opens up worlds of intrigue. But walljump.com is under construction. wall-jump is available, though.

Comment: This sounds like the name for a billiards SE.

Comment: $544 seems a bit steep...  :P

Answer (score -3):

### Bank-Shot (bank-shot.com)

Available? GoDaddy lists it for **$7.49** but there's also a bid price for **$544** listed... so I'm not sure how this is looking. But it looks all green here.

This is following the same logic as [this suggestion for Sleight Shot](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance-top-domain-name-pauseforhelp-com-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your/1090#1090), based on our currently leading logo that depicts a projectile banking off of a surface (or in less complex terms, a game of pong).

Bank Shot is a more common terminology used for various manner of angle-based skill shots, and the intent of this domain name is to associate our expertise with a well-known concept. So in that way, it has a greater strength than Sleight Shot (which expends a thesaurus to achieve uniqueness and alliteration), but it requires a hyphen.

Vote for this one if you'd like the familiar terminology and do not mind the hyphen.

Answer (score -3):

**gaming42.com**

42 is the answer to life, universe, and everything, so I think it fits well with the whole Q&A thing we got going on. It is also simple and easy to remember

It is available for $7.49

*Prices(s) are as retrieved from http://instantdomainsearch.com/. My perception is that this is the starting price or current "going price".*

Answer (score -3):

## Paragaming.com

Available.

The prefix "para", it means beside or beyond.

Comment: I like it ` ` ` `

Comment: Sounds like "paralyzed" or "paralympics"...

Comment: @badp: or parasailing, parachuting...

Answer (score -3):

Last second Entry, and still free:

### lavaboss.com

Answer (score -4):

famouslastwords.com
vitallastwords.com

both in the spirit of "ask before the end"

and also

anylastquests.com

a play on any last requests... (which is taken)

Answer (score -4):

onehithero.com & 1hithero.com

both free.

Answer (score -4):

**level30syndrome.com**

Available.

Reason? From [Bubble Bobble Revolution Page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_Bobble_Revolution#Major_Bug)

"A bug in the North American version makes levels 31-100 unplayable since there is no boss to fight in level 30."

The term "Level 30 Syndrome" was coined in a context of an impossibly hard level or game, both literally, and figuratively.

Comment: too long for my liking

Comment: I feel it isn't perfect, it doesn't hit the mark like SO, SF, SU, but it's close.

Answer (score -4):

## cakeisalie.com

Answer (score -4):

### gamingenlightenment.com

Available

Trying to spell 'enlightenment' might be a problem for some people though...

Comment: Too long. Ugly.

Comment: ... too hard to spell.

Answer (score -5):

How about **twisty-passages.com**

Comment: Y'know, I upvoted this, but I think upon reflection we might want to keep the reference to within the past, y'know, quarter-century or so. :)

Answer (score -5):

ToGameIsToWin.com

Answer (score -5):

joypadding.com

free

Answer (score -6):

Ok, ok, my last contribution:

- noobschool.com
- n00bskool.com

both available.

Comment: Keep posting your ideas, so long as they're new. :) My 16 suggestions totaled a -18 score last I checked...

Comment: These sound as though the site is NOT for experts, which is bad.

Answer (score -9):

## pwnpwn.com

available

Answer (score -10):

**faqthisgame**.com?

Comment: +1 for being clever. Maybe downvoter didn't get it ;)

Comment: -1, this isn't about _frequent_ questions, this is about _expert_ questions.

Comment: pronounce it aloud. No, the moment I say this, I dump the game for good