# Time is up - what is our domain name finally?

Tags: support, top-7, domain-name

Fun fact:

> #### In **85** days we cast **1,450** votes on **235** different domain names and we still don't have a clear winner.

Here, have a complimentary graph:

[image: That's a total of 719 upvotes and 731 downvotes.]

With roughly 5 days to go *and a logo to design still*, I guess this is where we give up and just ask the diamonds of this site to make the executive call and bestow **8bitlavapwnpwniesbossstagesixforhelp.com** or whatever name they deem the best onto us. :)

Comment: What are you asking here? Everyone knows we're running out of time, do you want to just keep adding on questions till we get a good name?

Comment: @tzenes, no, I'm saying that it is pointless to have further asking and further voting and that it is finally time for the executive call to be made by our and SE's moderation team. (Hence why I tagged this support.)

Comment: While that may be the case, and it's a cool graph, I think it's true that this is not a question. I suppose you could rephrase it as, "Is it time to give up and pick a random name?" but I don't know if that would be constructive either.

Comment: @Wik This is not a question, this is a support request. It can be objectively answered by he who makes the final call.

Comment: I'm guessing they'll go with pauseforhelp, they already own it and we didn't provide a good alternative when we had the chance...

Comment: @Juan It's not that clear cut, BossLevel has received a similar score in a much smaller time frame. Also, names need positive reception before they can be considered at all.

Comment: @Juan: There was also significant strong feeling against pauseforhelp. See several highly upvoted comments in the second thread. Pauseforhelp's high score was mainly due to a early bird  advantage.

Comment: @Macha, re: early birds. Hard to believe, early questions had the most upvoting _and_ the most downvoting.

Comment: badp > Not really hard to believe, if you think about it.  Questions/answers that have been around the longest are exposed to more general traffic, and thus voting than those that haven't.

Comment: @Gnome, it's _all_ types of voting we're talking here, actually early on there was more downvoting than upvoting.