# Any news about our launch? (When do I get my shiny coin-badges?)

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, user-interface, stack-exchange

I like the [coin-badges](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshots-v2). :D

More seriously, I presume we passed, especially because:

- [Jin was working on "finalizing" the design, until we find all the problems with it.](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5937#5937)
- [Area 51 says "This site is nearing the end of its beta will be launching very soon."](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming)

I know they're working hard on, you know, actually getting everything done required for launch, and we have the easy job of waiting for the new styling to appear within a couple of days, but I'm still selfishly curious:

**Anyone heard any more specific news about our launch?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are launched!

Answer (score 4):

Well, for starters, we don't have a logo.

[**Update:** We have a logo now! [Logo for Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/logo-for-gaming)]

I don't know how badly that's going to impact things, but it might have some effect. At least the web applications site had a logo for their site. We didn't quite get one yet.

As far as dates are concerned, Betas are supposed to last for ~90 days. Area 51 cites us with 89 days past. So that gives an estimate of 1 day left, or October 5th.

The other message is [an event on chat](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/7/Domain+Name?tab=schedule), entitled "Gaming (hopefully!) goes live!" Because it doesn't match the projected date of Oct. 5th (as according to Area 51 and [other occasional calculations](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/time-is-up-what-is-our-domain-name-finally)), the assumption is that this date is founded on something, possibly reliable. Whatever the case may be, October 7th looks to be a different candidate date for launch.

Comment: I guess I did make a leap... Jin does still have to work on a logo, even if it is just for "Gaming".

Comment: I just posted about the logo here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/logo-for-gaming

Comment: Oh hi, I posted that event. I guess I did my calculations wrong? (Does Area51 give a release date at all?)

Comment: Fixed the event.

Comment: Actually while area51 says we are at 89 days, my user profile claims I've visited the site for 91 days... odd

Comment: @Oak The site launched at 7 PM UTC, while our profiles track from midnight UTC. That's my guess for the discrepancy.

Comment: That or a glitch in the matrix -- (I woke up today wanted to use that phrase somewhere, this is the best context I found that makes the most sense)

Answer (score 2):

[Jin has said](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6556#6556) we're lanuching in 45 mins!

> 3pm EST, when we always launch our sites during the day