# Logo for Gaming

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, logo

Hi all,

Sorry about the delay on the logo. I was going to wait on the logo until we settle for a domain name. But due to the domain name policy change, I think I'll design a logo for the gaming theme, instead of tied to a particular name.

I checked the current [logo thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/logo-proposals-for-gaming) we have. The highest voted one is of a retro pixel art. I like this style a lot, as you have seen from the site design. I believe everyone who visits this site, new comers or seasoned users share one thing in common: they love games!

So here's my take. It's a pixel red heart, also the symbol for "life" in retro games.

[image]

The above are the Apple touch icon and favicon.

See it in action in the header: (click to see full res version)

[image]

Let me know what you think!

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area51-graduates/66552#66552)

Comment: I like it a lot. If only we were extralife.com... (actually it seems only [parked](http://www.mdnhinc.com/contact?dom=extralife.com))

Comment: @Tobias I'd rather something like zerocontinues.com (avail) to go with it

Comment: @badp: I don't know... It's been a while since I played a game with limited continues. But we obviously agree that the logo is a good source of inspiration for a good domain name

Comment: extralife was [suggested](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/868#868), btw.

Comment: I'd take either of those in a heart beat.

Comment: @tzenes: then upvote both. I can't find zerocontinues.com as a suggestion though

Comment: By the way, I'm still not sure how obvious is it that the "ask question" spaceship is actually a button... though I haven't seen the site in action.

Comment: @Oak, I agree with you. I think the "Questions" "Tags" "Users" "Badges" and espeically "unanswered" tabs need to differentiate themselves from the background a little more as well.

Comment: @Tobias I did a long time ago

Comment: A wild Jin-Logo appears. It uses Inspire on your Domain-Name Search. Its super-effective.

Comment: Awesome, I love it!

Answer (score 13):

That is just… inspiring. I instantly loved it. VERY well done.

Not to kick a hornet's nest, but that logo begs for a tagline or a site-wide meme. It would be *catchy* to talk about the site on the Internet as **♥ gaming** or **I ♥ gaming**.

The logo with a URL instantly becomes a great t-shirt or bumper sticker. 
Written out, it makes a *great* name for the site (Heart Gaming *or* I Heart Gaming). Heartgaming.com is already available. Iheartgaming.com is recently parked.

Nice.

Comment: HeartGaming I like.

Comment: why not "Love Gaming"? it focuses more on what the heart *represents* other than what it actually is.

Comment: (I meant as a tagline, the domain is obviously taken)

Comment: @Juan Manuel: I would say 'no' because "Love Gaming" misses the pop culture reference (i.e. the meme). When people see "I ♥ NY", they say "I heart New York". That's the appeal; the *joke*; the pop culture reference. Hence, "Heart Gaming."

Comment: @Juan Love Gaming sounds more like a dating site.

Answer (score 12):

Not only do I fully approve, I also find it cool that it forms a "love gaming" sentence :)

Comment: yeah, actually, why not stick with gaming? as in "I ♥ gaming"?

Comment: love that love gaming pitch

Comment: @Tobias, I added something like that to the suggestion thread, crediting you.

Answer (score 2):

First off, well done.

I discussed in [another thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area51-graduates/66539#66539) the major problems facing the Stackexchange branding.  Fortunately gaming faces almost none of them.

While Stack Exchange does still have a schizophrenic brand identity, the most stronger brand of Stack Overflow is actually beneficial to a site about video games.

What would programming experts know about video games? Probably a lot, they are programmers and nerds.

That said, we could do [worse](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance-top-domain-name-pauseforhelp-com-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your) than Gaming as our logo.

Comment: Ahem, I prefer geek. :-P

Comment: @ahsteele I prefer `Ogre`.  It has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 1):

Games that use hearts for life often used multiple hearts with some empty, or parts of the heart missing to show the life lost. [See Zelda for example](http://www.google.com/images?q=zelda+heart).

I'm betting you found all that in your own research. Have you tried either of those for the logo? I'm willing to bet we don't want multiple hearts, but I'm curious how everyone feels about one heart with a piece missing.

Good work, either way.

Comment: NES Zelda is where I got my idea from! I did think about having multiple hearts with some empty.. But it seems to me it'd send a message of some sort. But I don't know what it would mean. Also single heart is good for favicon/apple-touch size.

Comment: Have to agree with @Jin on this one. I feel that a (half) empty heart gives the impression that you're not as strong as you could be, or that you're dying, based on game nomenclature.

Comment: @TheQ On the one hand, low health is an emergency and we're all about fixing emergencies. On the better hand, the item that helps you in the emergency is generally a full heart, and you'll be at a full heart after visiting us. So it's double-win to use a full heart!

Comment: @Grace Agreed, and it seems befitting with the trend of comments for "I <3 Gaming" to use a full heart anyway.

Comment: @Jin: however, you could add an empty heart to the ask question button as in "help!!" **edit** although a rupee or heart container wouldn't hurt either

Comment: this just in: the empty hearts will make an appearance on the site! if you can find it... :)

Comment: @Jin Nice use of the empty hearts, good use without imposing negative connotations

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the bevel effect also come with a "dark highlight", or whatever the term for that might be?