# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, top-7, branding

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirts, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: I guess this question is not for snarky comments like noneofusisasdumbasallofus.com :P

Comment: Also, besides the tagline, our motto can be [Love Gaming](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/logo-for-gaming/1163#1163)

Comment: Shouldn't this be split into separate questions for Elevator Pitch, Tagline, and Motto?  Reading the answers as it stands is confusing.

Comment: @strixVaria: Not really separate questions because they can work together or even be very similar and possibly the same thing. There's no specific requirement to come up with each one. Focus on branding ideas for the site than the mechanics of "fill in these three blanks."

Comment: How exactly are these going to be used, if at all?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: They will be used as part of the site design or, possibly, a description in the side bar, depending on what the sites come up with.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a cue from badp

> Don't lose to the pros, learn from them.

Answer (score 3):

Motto:

> Winners don't do drugs!

Note: If it wasn't obvious, this is a joke entry... specifically, this text popped up before the title screen on late-80s/early-90s arcade machines, such as Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Mag Roader summed it up best in a different answer: the rep and badge parts of StackExchange site are themselves a kind of game, so "massively multiplayer" is a perfect phrase for a gaming.se tagline.  It references gaming with a common phrase, implies the community of gaming.se, and is catchy.

### Tagline:

> The massively multiplayer strategy guide for ANY game

or

> The massively multiplayer online strategy guide (Mag Roader's version)

Alternately:

- "User manual" instead of "strategy guide" (I adopted Mag Roader's wording)
- "every game" instead of "any game" - slightly different connotations
- "A" vs "The" at the start.  I like using "the" to stake our claim as the authority, but maybe that's too assertive.

Comment: Alternative to "user manual" - "strategy guide"?

Comment: Yes, "strategy guide" would work well in this format too.  I'm not sure which I prefer.

Comment: I switched it to "strategy guide"

Comment: I also prefer saying "Online" like "Massively Multiplayer Online Strategy Guide". I also don't care for the "for any game" - doesn't add much.

Comment: My intent with "for any game" is to make it clear that this isn't for any particular single game.  I like "MMOSG" just fine, but my only worry is that it sounds like it's a strategy guide for some single specific online game.
I definitely don't like stringing them together in "The massively multiplayer online strategy guide for any game" because that just feels too long.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this one. "Massively multiplayer" is kind of a loaded phrase, even if it *is* referring to the site itself and not the genre the site focuses on.

Comment: I agree with @Brant, when a phrase contains "massively multiplayer" I'll move on

Answer (score 3):

Tagline:
The only game guide you'll ever need.

Answer (score 3):

> Learn from the best how to beat the
>   rest.

Answer (score 3):

**Elevator Pitch**: Whether you're intent on saving a princess, or [eating her corpse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat), we have the expert advice you need.

Answer (score 2):

As no one's jumped in with a pitch yet, here's one to start it off:

> Q&A site for anyone who loves and is
>   passionate about gaming that embraces
>   all platforms, eras and abilities.

Comment: I refuse you embrace the WonderSwan and the Virtual Boy. Call it a personal pet peeve. :)

Comment: I embrace the Virtual Boy!

Comment: I think you'd have to balance any personal peeves against the likelihood of anyone coming here to ask about obscure, ancient hardware. Personally I'm drawing the line at Game & Watch Snoopy Tennis.

Comment: If someone showed up here to ask about, say, the 'Amiga CD 32', I'm sure they'd still get an answer.

Comment: Did this answer essentially "win"? It's the first description under the titular stuff on the main site's About page.

Answer (score 2):

> Learn to play with gamers who love to play.

Comment: This is not a clan.

Comment: What if we changed "with" to "from": "Learn to play from gamers who love to play."

Comment: @Badp I'm not sure how this relates to clans. @Strix The reason I did not go with "from" is that the whole SE network is about learning together, eventually contributing back to the community you are learning from. Maybe we don't need that forced into our tagline, but it is an important part of who we are.

Comment: @Strix As one cannot ping two commenters in one comment... ping! ♪

Comment: I can't say this one does anything for me. I mean it's not like most of us will be playing anything *together* anytime soon.

Comment: Also, the phrase 'learn to play' implies (to me anyway) that our users are doing just that: learning to play games they have never played before, as opposed to asking informed questions about games we are (mostly) already experienced with.  It just seems more juvenile to me.

Comment: Also "Learn to play" (or "L2P" as the kids say these days) has negative connotations as a common insult from the more childish section of MMO players.

Answer (score 2):

Motto (for real this time):

> Get Your Game On

or if that's too close to someone else's logo:

> Game On

Answer (score 2):

Elevator Pitch:

> Lost in a Level?  Quest questions?
>   Seeking strategy suggestions? Ask your
>   video gaming questions here!

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I like the last sentence... anyone have suggestions to improve it?

Comment: I like the Alliteration, but agreed about the last sentence.

Comment: Do people still call them "video games" these days, I think of that term from the early days of C&VG magazine? Maybe just "*Ask your gaming questions here!*" Or to continue on the alliteration theme "*Ask the gaming gurus here!*"

Comment: @GAThrawn As much as our domain and name is just "gaming", gaming does refer to a lot of other things like P&P, LARPs, and board games (in fact, the Gaming Club at my college was about board games and had nothing to do with video games), all of which are off-topic here. I think having our tagline be clearer than our domain can be a useful thing. Video game might be an "old" name, but has it ever changed?

Comment: Good point, and it's hard to think of another term that would as inclusive, of all the different types that we do want to include.

Answer (score 2):

### **Tagline:**

'Questions for the masters, answers for the masses.'

Comment: I like the first tagline, but little else. Would like to see these split though, so they could be voted on individually.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Wasn't sure if posting 4 times was acceptable.  I'll just repost a few of them.

Comment: Sounds elitist :P

Comment: @Nick > And who doesn't love that, right?  ;)

Comment: How about "Answers from the Masters" ?

Comment: @Pure > I don't like the fit of Masters/Masters...  What about "Questions from the masses, answers from the masters"?

Answer (score 2):

### **Motto:**

A winner **CAN** be you!

(If you're familliar with retro gaming, I'm sure you will get the reference.)

Comment: +1: A winner is you!

Answer (score 2):

**Elevator pitch:**
Nothing but the best and fastest answers to your gaming questions, so you can get back to the game.

Comment: Like this one, but maybe it could be shortened just a bit, seems kind of clunky.  Maybe remove "any of" and just have 'answers to your gaming questions' ?

Answer (score 1):

<s>You could keep losing to the pros, or you could man up and ask 'em.</s>

You could keep getting owned by the pros, or you could own up and ask 'em.

Comment: Mess with the best, die like the rest.

Comment: I like the concept of this tagline, but I'd like the tagline a lot more if we used something besides "man up".

Comment: @grace How about this then? I wish I was more proficient in English...

Comment: @badp, You mean - "I wish I **were** more proficient in English." `:P`

Comment: @Justin: Explanation please? I don't get it.

Comment: @Macha http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/was-vs-were-word-usage-in-stack-overflow-ad-image

Answer (score 1):

### Motto:

Thank you for helping us help you help us all!

(I'm sure most of you get **this** reference, however I think this one is a bit lengthy and slightly plagiaristic.)

Comment: [http://thankyouforhelpingushelpyouhelpusall.net/](http://thankyouforhelpingushelpyouhelpusall.net/)

Comment: I just made that my homepage.

Comment: +1: I like this one... as long as people get the reference.

Comment: Too obscure, in my opinion.  I've played Portal through twice and didn't get the reference.

Comment: @lilserf I think you're right, gaming references like this probably aren't the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

### Elevator Pitch:

[The] Home of the true Wizards.  This is serious business.

---

Alternatively replace the second line with any of:

- 'We mean business'
- 'We take gaming seriously'
- 'We're serious about gaming'

Answer (score 0):

Gaming answers for all, its like guidebooks and FAQs had an awesome baby

ok, maybe thats a little too snarky but I like it

Answer (score 0):

```
Last checkpoint
```

Comment: I don't see how this fits into any of the 3 categories.

Answer (score -1):

considering the current heart logo, here is a motto:

## love for gamers

Comment: That makes it sound like a gamer's dating site.  That's just ... no, we're not ... *horribly* ...  **NOT GOING TO HAPPEN**.

Comment: ^ What he said.  :P

Answer (score -3):

> It's GameFAQs -- but faster and about questions you actually have.

Comment: It's inaccurate and antagonistic. I think we're better served by being an ally to GameFAQs rather than a rival.

Comment: @Grace Being antagonistic is [actually a plus...](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html) That said I might have picked the _wrong_ enemy.

Comment: Regardless I don't think you want to mention them directly in your pitch. Also, you can definitely come up with something that contrasts your site with other, similar sites without needing to talk about them negatively.

Comment: @Mag ["Stackoverflow is sort of like the anti-experts-exchange (minus the nausea-inducing sleaze and quasi-legal search engine gaming) meets wikipedia meets programming reddit."](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us.html)