# Where did the Arqade name come from?

Tags: support

I'm just curious, what the origins of the "Arqade" name for the site are. Are there any reasons it wasn't just called Gaming?

Comment: Oof. There are a couple of relevant meta posts. I wonder if I can dig them up.

Comment: Here's two relevant meta posts from the days of yore, but the other half of the story lies in some SO Blog posts, which I can't find. [This](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site/458#458) and [This](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance-top-domain-name-pauseforhelp-com-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your/1176#1176)

Comment: gaming.com was of course already taken.

Comment: And for the record, it originally was just, "Gaming.Stackexchange". Arqade came later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the announcement post [Introducing Arqade!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4821/28182), it was suggested in a [community chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4376663#4376663) about the topic:

> We recently have put a lot of effort in coming up with a unique brand name for this community. As you know, naming is hard! After numerous brain storming sessions, we found a great name(and was able to obtain the domain name). It was [suggested](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4589/16718) in a [community chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4376663#4376663), and "Arqade" was chosen. "Arqade," obviously playing off the word "arcade," reflects what this site is about. It's a place where gamers hang out, answer each other's questions or simply chit in the chatroom. As a bonus, "Arqade" even contains the acronym "QA" in it!

Before this chat took place, there were [suggestion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/28182) [posts](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1259/28182) for coming up with a good name, however according to the meta post [Chat room for suggesting a new name for Gaming.SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4589/16718):

> We took these suggestions into consideration, and have gone through several rounds of brainstorming to try to come up with alternatives. Unfortunately, many of our ideas for new domain names are unavailable.

A set of criteria was defined for suggesting names and the chat room was opened for suggestions.

The rest, as they say, is history.

Comment: Thanks for that :). I didn't even realise the QA part of the name!