# First Question on Arqade?

Tags: discussion

Simple question, what was the first question to be asked on Arqade? And as a follow up, what was the first question posted to the Arqade Meta?

Comment: Just get URL and put 1 after /questions/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if the theory of question numbering is correct, this is the first main site question (question number of 1).

[What is a good strategy to deal with lots of engineers turtling on the other team?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-a-good-strategy-to-deal-with-lots-of-engineers-turtling-on-the-other-tea)

and this is the first meta question:

[Suggest a domain name for this site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site)

Comment: The first meta question was a duplicate? Impressive. ;)